# Brightness/contrast correction first before image alignment or vice versa?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

need your help with the following. I have 3 same stationary object image that were captured per 30mins interval. I have lock the camera and object in position and the room was left dark but still I ended up with 3 different exposure/brightness/gamma images and the object move a little as well.
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GBhG.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMAFk.jpg)

What I was trying to do is to adjust alignment, brightness/gamma/contrast 2nd and 3rd images in reference to 1st images. I have solution on how to align the image using ECCtransform method below:

```
import os, sys
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\"
path1 = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\aligned\\"

def alignment():
    for i in range(1,4):
        # Read the images to be aligned
        im1 =  cv2.imread(path + '1.png')
        im2 =  cv2.imread(path + '%d.png' %(i))
        print(i)

        # Convert images to grayscale
        im1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        im2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Find size of image1
        sz = im1.shape

        # Define the motion model
        warp_mode = cv2.MOTION_TRANSLATION

        # Define 2x3 or 3x3 matrices and initialize the matrix to identity
        if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY :
            warp_matrix = np.eye(3, 3, dtype=np.float32)
        else :
            warp_matrix = np.eye(2, 3, dtype=np.float32)
        # Specify the number of iterations.
        number_of_iterations = 5000;

        # Specify the threshold of the increment
        # in the correlation coefficient between two iterations
        termination_eps = 1e-10;

        # Define termination criteria
        criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, number_of_iterations,  termination_eps)

        # Run the ECC algorithm. The results are stored in warp_matrix.
        (cc, warp_matrix) = cv2.findTransformECC(im1_gray, im2_gray, warp_matrix, warp_mode, criteria)


        if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY :
            # Use warpPerspective for Homography 
            im2_aligned = cv2.warpPerspective (im2, warp_matrix, (sz[1],sz[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
        else :
            # Use warpAffine for Translation, Euclidean and Affine
            im2_aligned = cv2.warpAffine(im2, warp_matrix, (sz[1],sz[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP);

        cv2.imwrite(path1 + "%d.png" % (i), im2_aligned )

alignment()
```

My question are, which is the better way to go? Is the sequence matter?
By taking first image as standard reference:

Should I perform transformECC image alignment first so that I can adjust the brightness/exposure of my images accurately?

OR

I should adjust the brightness/exposure first so that I aligned the photo accurately?

I am still thinking way to adjust my 2nd and 3rd images brightness/exposure with reference to 1st images. Any ideas is welcomed and appreciated !!!!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe2Fk.jpg <<third images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most cost functions for alignment, I'd encourage you to pre-process (notable exceptions include mutual information).  However, the Enhanced Cross Correlation used by findTransformEcc seems to be robust to photometric distortion (quoting http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4515873/: "In this work we propose the use of a modified version of the correlation coefficient as a performance criterion for the image alignment problem. The proposed modification has the desirable characteristic of being invariant with respect to photometric distortions.")  So, it should be fine doing the photometric adjustment either before or after.